# Find the expected net profit

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I am trying to solve the following question (7.4 from Paul Meyer's "Introductory probability and Statistics", 2nd ed.):
In the manufacture of petroleum, the distilling temperature, say $T$ (degrees centigrade), is crucial in determining the quality of the final product. Suppose that $T$ is considered as a random variable uniformly distributed over $(150,300)$.
Suppose that it costs $C_1$ dollars to produce one gallon of petroleum. If the oil distils at a temperature less than $200°C$, the product is known as naptha and sells for $C_2$ dollars per gallon. If it is distilled at a temperature greater than $200°C$, it is known as refined oil destillate and sells for $C_3$ dollars per gallon. Find the expected net profit (per gallon).

I have written the density function of the net profit as:

$P(T) = C_2 - C_1$ , if $T \lt 200°C$
$P(T) = C_3 - C_1$ , if $T \gt 200°C$

And applied in the expected value formula for continuos random variables:

$E(P) = \int_{150}^{200} t(C_2-C_1)dt + \int_{200}^{300} t(C_3-C_1)dt$

But i got a different answer from the one on the back of the book, which is: $1/3(2C_3 + C_2 - 3C_1)$.

I believe my mistake was in the way i described the density function. Can you help me solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For mean value, you must divide by the width of the interval.

Comment: @BarryCarter what should be the numerator? The result of the integrals?

Comment: The difference in the limits of the integrals, eg, 50 and 100

Comment: @BarryCarter it worked, i got the right answer. But why works? Where this comes from?

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a factor $t$ inside your integrals.  They should just integrate the constant profits over the interval.  You don't need to do integrals for this question.  If the temperature is chosen uniformly the chance is $\frac 13$ it is below $200$ and $\frac 23$ it is above.  Your expected profit is then
$$\frac 13(C_2-C_1)+\frac 23(C_3-C_1)$$
You also need to divide by $150$, the length of the interval.  My $\frac 13$ would be the same as your $\frac {50}{150}.  If you make those two corrections you will get the book answer.